# How do I use KeePass app on other computer?

Tags: 14.04, encryption, keepass

I generated several passwords using KeePass on one of my computers.  How do I access KeePass with all my passwords on another computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to copy the keepass icon in my home folder to a usb drive then plug the drive to my other computer, copy and paiste it to my home folder.  Then I simply clicked on the open folder icon and the account file is showing.  I just clicked it and hit open then entered my master password and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Keepass uses a password safe which is nothing more or less than an encrypted file. So the only thing you have to do is install Keepass and replace the empty password file by one that you've taken from another computer and that contains all your passwords.

Comment: Can you give me step by step on where to go

Comment: Step by step?! You just install Keepass like you did earlier on the computer you mentioned in the question, then locate the password file and copy it to the freshly installed computer. It is really easy to do.

Comment: Im assuming when you open keepass it gives u the option to enter your master password and you do so to open a account .   But It is not showing my account above it is showing a different accout(another that I made).  I went to open file folder icon and entered the file name and path and it says it doesn't exist..

Comment: As far as I know you can choose to open a certain assword file so choose the correct one that contains your passwords or do some research for yourself how to achieve this: http://keepass.info/help/base/cmdline.html

Answer (score 0):

KeePass is an *application* in the traditional way and not an *"app"*, which means by default it **doesn't use online storage** or syncing and its primary use is to *directly* work with files on the local computer/device. Also KeePass is not an online service like some of it's competitors.

The *files* KeePass creates for you are password **databases**. If you don't set up syncing yourself with the [mechanisms](http://keepass.info/help/v2/sync.html) and [plugins](http://keepass.info/plugins.html) offered then you have to transfer the these databases manually and select to open them with KeePass or a compatible application to access your data. Not long ago this was how applications where typically used: users were required to know how to feed data to an application and they were responsible for **backups** too.

Answer (score 0):

I use KeePassX or even KeePass on multiple systems. The database file is encrypted and in my case shared via a cloud memory, eg Dropbox or OneCloud. For more security I use a encrypted filesystem to synchronize.

Answer (score 0):

Install KeePass on the other computer. KeePass uses single files as data storage. You created this file when you first used KeePass. In the dialog which pops up every time you open the Application (which also asks you for the password) you can see the path of the data file you're using.

You need to put this file in a cloud storage like Dropbox, copy.com, etc. Then you choose the same file on the other computer.